# Cordova-file-plugin creating function to read from file

Tags: cordova

This is my code in function pnrread() cordova file plugin is used to read from file.
but when i call pnrread() then in alert box it return "undefined".
file pnr.txt have data as when console.log(this.result) gives file  data  but alert doesn't give.

```
alert(pnrread);
function pnrread(){
       window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, function(fs) {
        fs.getFile("pnr.txt",{ create: false, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
            console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
               var res=this.result;
               console.log(this.result)
                return res; 
        };
            reader.readAsText(file);
            });
        },pnrCreateFile);
    })   
    }
}
```

Documentation of cordova-file-plugin : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/